# jQuery / javascript watch for new elements created in contenteditable space

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This is an curiosity question.  I can do without it, but was wondering if it's possible to do.

I have a contentEditable div that a user can input text into.  They can optionally edit the html and add divs with html. I'd like to look for a div with a specific class that they might create....such as `<div class="random"></div>` and do something with that element.

Is there a "created" event with javascript or jQuery that I can watch for?

```
jQuery(".random").live("created", function(){});
```

I realize I can watch the DOMSubtreeModified, but that adds a lot of overhead...especially since people will be typing on the page.  It will push an event every time someone types a letter.

Anyways, if you can think of something, would be fun to know.

Comment: The [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin might help here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know is to use the [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) plugin, but it's very old (i think it has been discontinued since the live() function appeared in jquery)